# Complex input to WebApi2 function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I've got this class in my Model:

```
    public class GetDocParams {
        public string LogonTicket { get; set; }
        public int CliRid { get; set; }
        public string[] ValPairs { get; set; }
        public string SortBy  { get; set; }
        public int StartRec  { get; set; }
        public int EndRec  { get; set; }
    }
```

This is going to be used as input to a WebApi2 function to retrieve query results from Entity Framework.

The function takes the valPairs from input and uses it to build a query that sorts by the passed pairs, i.e.

```
CLI_RID=111111 
DOC_NAME=Letter
```

would create the SQL:

```
WHERE CLI_RID = 111111 
 AND  DOC_NAME = 'Letter'
```

I'm kind of curious, how would I pass the ValPairs, using ajax and/or WebClient?
GET or POST doesn't matter.

Comment: You really should do some sanitation on those parameters

Comment: What do you mean by "WebClient"?

Comment: How would you pass `ValPairs` ***where***? To another WebApi function? To a web page? From a web page?  `GET` and `POST` don't do the same thing.  It's not really clear what you are asking here.

Comment: Will you have any other key-value pairs other than `CLI_RID` and `DOC_NAME`? If you don't, are you able to create a new class for `ValPairs` with those two as member variables?

Comment: @TamasIonut, The "sanitation" is done in the WebApi2 method and if you have to ask what WebClient is, then you don't know .Net.

Comment: @JiaJian, yes, there may be more, but I don't think we'll ever have more than 3 name/value pairss

Comment: @Claies,  "This is going to be used as input to a WebApi2". What isn't clear about that? Yes, I know that GET and POST aren't the same thing but the WebApi2 function can be written to support both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to add a new class for `ValPair`, like the following.

```
public class GetDocParams {
    public string LogonTicket { get; set; }
    public int CliRid { get; set; }
    public ValPair[] ValPairs { get; set; }
    public string SortBy  { get; set; }
    public int StartRec  { get; set; }
    public int EndRec  { get; set; }
}

public class ValPair {
    public int CLI_RID { get; set; }
    public string DOC_NAME { get; set; }
}
```

And you can pass values to the parameters via the following `GET` API call:
`http://www.example.com/api/docs/getDocParams?LogonTicket=111&ValPairs[0][CLI_RID]=111111&ValPairs[0][DOC_NAME]=Letter&ValPairs[1][CLI_RID]=22222&ValPairs[1][DOC_NAME]=document&...`.

This should work if you know the names of the keys.

Comment: With some of our DOC_NAME values can be quite long, this may cause us to run into URL length limits. Using as a POST could probably do it, though. Although the ValPair class needs to be "generic" as we don't know what columns they will want to sort by.

Comment: Hi! Wanted to know if you've manage to solve your problem? You could try having your Web API method accept a `dynamic` type parameter - you can opt not to use a model in this case. And yes, you should `POST` as a JSON array and let your Web API method deserialize it.